# Relay HTTP requests to multiple web server

Tags: web-services, amazon-web-services, http

We have our web server cluster in the AWS's US-WEST-2 region reading/writing to Postgres RDS in the same region. As per AWS's SLA a region can be down for 22 mins in a month.

To mitigate this downtime of 22 min when ever it happens. I am setting up another cluster in US-EAST-1 region with it's own RDS.

To have both the clusters in sync I want the PUT requests to be relayed to both the clusters in US-WEST-2 and US-EAST-1. Is there a web proxy/AWS service which can help me?

Comment: Why aren't you using database replication?

Comment: @JakubKania AWS provides only read replication.

Comment: It provides Multi-AZ deployment which is essentialy R/W replication in the same region. For cross-region fallover you can promote the read replica to master.

Comment: But once the outage resolves getting things running back in the original configuration can be problematic as the old master DB is out of sync with the new master.

Comment: Multi-AZ takes care of it on it's own.